# LibGDX renders after phone on and off

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently developing a LibGDX game on Android, but when I boot it up on PC (desktop version) it works alright, but once I open it up on my phone (which is connected to my PC with developer mode turned on), it first displays the glClear color instead of the sprites and objects it used to display.

But when I turn my phone on and off (Stand-by/on again), it does actually display all the sprites and objects like on the desktop version.

Screenshot:
[Before I turned my phone on and off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Jfa.png)

[After I turned my phone on and off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPF9O.png)

This is the code from my main class (render method only)

```
@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(sm.getCurrentScreen() != null){
        update();
        sm.getCurrentScreen().render(sb);
    }

}
```

My GameScreen class (is equals to the currentscreen in the method above)

```
    @Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.begin();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.draw(TextureManager.background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    em.renderEntities(sb);

    sb.end();
}
```

Once again, it does work on the PC and it does fully work like it should when I turn my phone on and off. Of course when I'm going to release the game it's not nice that you have to turn your phone on and off before you can start playing. The update() method (see code in main class) however does seem to work when the rest of the screen is black.

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Comment: Have you tried using `AssetManager` for loading textures? Maybe the way you are loading them in memory is bad. By the way, i hope your textures are not declared static.

Comment: @Kush I tried it using the AssetManager and it still doesn't work. And my textures aren't static.